# jQuery UI Autocomplete .result is not a function woes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've done some searching, and this seems to be a not uncommon problem, but none of the solutions posted seem to be working for me.

I've tried a few different methods:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( "#on-good-terms-add-term" ).autocomplete({
        source: ongoodtermsavailableTags,
    });

    jQuery( "#on-good-terms-add-term" ).result(function(event, data, formatted) { alert(data); });
});
```

and

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( "#on-good-terms-add-term" ).autocomplete({
        source: ongoodtermsavailableTags,
    }).result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

});

Both give me the same console error. Would appreciate any assistance. Thanks

Comment: Result is not a function of the jQuery library (as you have used it here) and it is not an event of the [jQuery UI autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). Could you please explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I've got an <input> tag. I'm getting the autocomplete dropdown like I should, and when I choose one, I want to (for the moment) get an alert with the selected value. How is the way I'm using it different than the example: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/result

Comment: If you are using the plugin documented there, then it is not part of the jQuery UI family of widgets. If you are using jQuery UI's autocomplete widget, then you are not reading the correct documentation for that library. Could you confirm which script you are using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To trigger an event when the user selects a search result with the [jQuery UI autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete), you can initialize your constructor as follows with an event handler for "select":

```
jQuery("#on-good-terms-add-term").autocomplete({
    source: ongoodtermsavailableTags,
    select: function(e, ui) {
         alert("User selected: " + ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: I had the same problem for a while. I just realized I've been referencing documentation for a deprecated autocomplete plugin, which had the result function. From what I gather, a lot of people had the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

My error was that I had the file **autocomplete-rails.js** as well as the provided **rails.js** in my *assets/javascripts folder*. Deleting the file was the solution