# undefine is not a function jquery auto complete

Tags: autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

When trying to handle the data returned from autocomplete result set this always happens.

Any clue on this issue?

```
$("#search").autocomplete(suggest_url,{
    max:100,
    delay:10, 
    selectFirst: false

}).result(function(event, data, formatted)
{
    do_search(true);
});
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Such error happens only if you are trying to call a function, but it is not a function.

```
x = 123;
x();  // produces «number is not a function

y = undefined;
y();  // produces exactly «TypeError: undefined is not a function»
```

«**Uncaught** type error» indicates that exception caused inside the lambla-style function. Thus, I hope, it is something wrong with *do_searh* identifier. Try to **alert(do_searh)** before calling it.

**>>> UPDATE**

This questions refers to another: 
[jQuery UI Autocomplete .result is not a function woes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068504/jquery-ui-autocomplete-result-is-not-a-function-woes)

Comment: with out do_search the same error occurs!! auto complete result function is depreciated?

Comment: Please, find «update» of the answer. Your problem was always discussed here.